# How can empty or reset or clear this type array?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, indexoutofrangeexception

I have one specific array integer

```
 Dim ArrayWinRandomNumber(0 To 5) As Integer
```

and another function on take it

```
Private Sub repetido()
    For x = 0 To 5
        Randomize()
        Dim RandomNumber As Integer
        RandomNumber = CInt(Int((49 * Rnd()) + 1))
        For y = 0 To 5
            If RandomNumber = ArrayWinRandomNumber(y) Then
                repetido()
            End If
        Next
        ArrayWinRandomNumber(x) = RandomNumber
    Next x
    ordenar()
End Sub
```

The problem is, that the first time he called repeated, it works fine, but if you call back a second time. I returned `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Comment: `ReDim ArrayWinRandomNumber(0 To 5)`  or `Array.Clear(ArrayWinRandomNumber, 0, 6)`  there are better ways to get a set of non repeating values though

Comment: Did you see my answer? You can achieve array of random numbers with 1 line of code

Comment: What does the sub ordenar() do? I ran this code without that sub and it ran just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do something like this (you're using vb.net like vb6)

```
Imports System.Linq
. . . . . . . . .  . .
Dim r as new Random()
Dim items() as Integer = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(Function(i) r.Next()).ToArray()

For Each i as Integer in items
    console.WriteLine("Item val: " & i)
Next
```

It will give you array of random numbers any time